# Thingsboard disconnectes MQTT clients

Tags: mqtt, iot, esp32, thingsboard

I try to connect a few ESP32s with **Thingsbaord via MQTT** using the PubSubClient library.
Unfortunately it seems I am not able to connect multiple devices subscribing the same topic.

- using the same client-id --> one client kicks out the other client
- using different client-id but same username (token) --> one clientkicks out the other client
- using different client-ids and different usernames --> more devices can connect to Thingsboard at the same time, but after subscribing to `v1/devices/me/attributes` and `v1/gateway/attributes` they kick each other out and have to reconnect. In the Thingsboard-log disconnect, connect, disconnect... is shown.
  Using a different MQTT-broker everything works, so I think it has to be the configuration of Thingsboard-MQTT or the fact that two devices try to subscribe to the same topic.

The same problem occurs using an Andorid MQTT-client so its not the ESP or the liraray.

Does anyone has similar issues and found a workaround?

Thanks